# Copy next lines in macro

Tags: c++, c++11, macros

I would like to make a 'decorator' like macro. The way it would look like:

```
#define CLASS(name) \
class name\
{\
    void DoClassStuff()\
    {\
        int result = //COPY CODE FROM THE NEXT LINES AND CALL IT;\
    }\
};

CLASS(MyClass)
int GonnaBeCopied() {
   return 10;
}
```

The result should look like:

```
class MyClass
{
    void DoClassStuff()
    {
        int result = GonnaBeCopied();
    }
};
```

Comment: What is your use case? Maybe using macros is going about it the wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that. The macro takes the name, **CLASS** in your case, to identify the macro, then the contents within the parentheses as parameters to the macro. Everything after that is ignored by the  macro processor and is processed by the compiler normally.

The only way to include that code in the macro is to make it part of the parameters in the macro.

P.S. Macros should only be used when absolutely necessary. They can obscure code and create difficult to identify errors.